# exec() and variable scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sure this has been asked and answered, but I couldn't find it specifically:

I'm just picking up Python and I'm not understanding a **variable scope issue**.

**I've simplified the problem to the following:**

Case 1:

```
def lev1():
   exec("aaa=123")
   print("lev1:",aaa)

lev1()
```

Case 2:

```
def lev1():
   global aaa
   exec("aaa=123")
   print("lev1:",aaa)

lev1()
```

Case 3:

```
def lev1():
   exec("global aaa ; aaa=123")
   print("lev1:",aaa)

lev1()
```

- `Case 1` and `Case 2` have `aaa` undefined in the print statement.
- `Case 3` works. Where does `aaa` actually exist in `Case 1` and `Case 2`?
- Is there a way to access `aaa` in Case 1 without a `global` declaration?

Answer (score 17):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> **Note:** The default *locals* act as described for function [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) below: modifications to the default *locals* dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit *locals* dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on *locals* after function [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) returns.

In other words, if you call `exec` with one argument, you're not supposed to try to assign any variables, and Python doesn't promise what will happen if you try.

You can have the `exec`uted code assign to globals by passing `globals()` explicitly. (With an explicit `globals` dict and no explicit `locals` dict, `exec` will use the same dict for both globals and locals.)

```
def lev1():
   exec("aaa=123", globals())
   print("lev1:", aaa)

lev1()
```

Comment: the problem is that you have actually modified 'aaa' in the global scope and not in the scope of the function. To verify, put 'aaa = None' on the first line of the lev1()

Comment: @ikamen: Well, yeah. I was pretty explicit about this assigning to globals. You can't assign to a function's locals with `exec`.