# Global name is not defined when running script with closures with execfile

Tags: python, python-2.x, execfile

I am trying to run `script2` from `script1` with `execfile` and `script2` contains closures:

> script1.py

```
MyVar1 = 'value1'


def fun1():
    print(MyVar1)


def fun2():
    execfile('script2.py')

fun1()
fun2()
```

> script2.py

```
MyVar2 = 'value2'


def fun1():
    print(MyVar2)


fun1()
```

An error occurs

```
  File "...script1.py", line 12, in <module>
    fun2()
  File "...script1.py", line 9, in fun2
    execfile('script2.py')
  File "script2.py", line 8, in <module>
    fun1()
  File "script2.py", line 5, in fun1
    print(MyVar2)
NameError: global name 'MyVar2' is not defined
```

How to fix `script1` still using `execfile`?

**UPDATE**

If it is impossible with `execfile` then how to do otherwise?

Comment: Why are you determined to use `execfile`?

Comment: Same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535284/exec-and-variable-scope

Comment: @user2357112 because I was thinking it is usable function; if it doesn't, then OK, how to do otherwise

Answer (score -1):

```
MyVar2 = 'value2'

def fun1():
    global MyVar2
    print(MyVar2)

fun1()
```

The fix needs to be done in script 2 actually.

Comment: Downvoter. Please educate me thats wrong in my understanding?

Comment: `fun1` isn't going to look for a local `MyVar2` anyway, since `fun1` contains no assignments to `MyVar2`.

Comment: The problem is in how `execfile` almost-but-not-really executes the contents of `script2.py` in the local namespace of `fun2` from `script1`.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Thanks for correcting my understanding abt this. Edited the ans to exclude the wrong explanation. Sorry for that.