# ast execution produces different result in a function vs module scope

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

**Edit**: the problem is not related to `ast` module.

it can be reproduced with just using `exec`:

```
y = None

exec("y = 5.0")
print(y)  # prints 5.0
```

vs

```
def foo():
    y = None

    exec("y = 5.0")
    print(y)

foo()  # prints None
```

---

**Original question:**

I am generating code programmatically using `ast` module. I have following code, that works:

```
import ast

num = ast.Num(n=5.)
y = None
assign = ast.Assign(targets=[ast.Name(id='y', ctx=ast.Store())], value=num)
tree = ast.Module(body=[assign], type_ignores=[])
ast.fix_missing_locations(tree)
c = compile(tree, filename="", mode="exec")
exec(c)  # replaces the value of 'y' with 5.0

print(y) # prints 5.0
```

However, as soon as I wrap this code in a function, it stops working:

```
import ast

def foo():
    num = ast.Num(n=5.)

    y = None
    assign = ast.Assign(targets=[ast.Name(id='y', ctx=ast.Store())], value=num)
    tree = ast.Module(body=[assign], type_ignores=[])
    ast.fix_missing_locations(tree)
    c = compile(tree, filename="", mode="exec")
    exec(c)

    print(y)

foo()  # prints None
```

This is the first time I see python code behave differently after being moved inside a function. I have checked and assignment does not put `y` in the module (locals) either:

`print(y)  # NameError: name 'y' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in a function, you can capture the assignments into any dictionary that will function as the scope for the executed statements:

```
def foo():
    scope = {}
    exec("y = 5.0", scope)
    print(scope['y'])

foo()  # prints 5.0
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. A question remains - where did the assignment go when we left scope unspecified? it's not module globals.

Answer (score 0):

Variable Y is declared in function scope and its not available outside of it. If you want Y to be available post function call return it or use a global.

Update:
See my comment in relation to exec and scopes: [exec() and variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535284/exec-and-variable-scope)

Comment: Indeed, just noticed it. 
Tried to execute your code locally but it fails. What python version do you use?

Comment: py 3.7 or 3.8-dev

Comment: Answer might not been most accurate but it touches on the problem of scopes. See already given answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535284/exec-and-variable-scope