# Incrementing integer using variable name string

Tags: python-3.x, exec

I'm doing the following in the python interpreter and it works:

```
rhce=rhcsa=0
args=['rhce','rhcsa']
for cert in args:
    exec(cert+'+=1')
    print(eval(cert))

>>> 1
>>> 1
```

As you can see the variable is incremented, whether you use print(rhce) or print(eval(cert)). However, when I put the exact same snippet of code inside a class function, it no longer works. No exceptions are thrown, but the variable never increments. It's like the exec is not working:

```
def addCertUser(self,userid,args):
    rhcsa=rhce=0

    print(args)
    try:
        for cert in args:
            exec(cert+'+=1')
            print(eval(cert))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


>>> ['rhce', 'rhcsa']
>>> 0
>>> 0
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: why do you need to use eval? why not just use a dict to map names to int values?

Comment: You're not showing how you call the function. It is necessary to provide a [mre]

Comment: 1. I don't know, why it doesn't work, but the way to make it work is to replace `rhcsa = rhce = 0` with `exec("rhcsa = rhce = 0")`
2. As @ChrisDoyle had mentioned, using eval and exec in production code is really a bad practice, you may want to use the following: https://pastebin.com/PTV5SAbd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its never a good idea to eval or exec code, 99 times out of 100 there is a better way to do it. In this case unless you have any other reason that really needs to use eval and exec you could achieve what your trying with a dict. it can hold a key ("name") used to reference or look up your value quite safely.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_counts = {
            'rhce': 0,
            'rhcsa': 0
        }
    def add_cert_user(self, userid, args):
        print("start of function", self.my_counts)
        for cert in args:
            if cert  in self.my_counts:
                self.my_counts[cert] += 1
        print("end of function", self.my_counts)

me = MyClass()
args = ['rhce','rhcsa']
me.add_cert_user("test", args)
me.add_cert_user("test", args)
me.add_cert_user("test", args)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
start of function {'rhce': 0, 'rhcsa': 0}
end of function {'rhce': 1, 'rhcsa': 1}
start of function {'rhce': 1, 'rhcsa': 1}
end of function {'rhce': 2, 'rhcsa': 2}
start of function {'rhce': 2, 'rhcsa': 2}
end of function {'rhce': 3, 'rhcsa': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for getting a different result is that the scope of the variables you're trying to modify dynamically has changed between the 2 examples, from a module level scope to local function scope.

Using exec to modify local variables does not guarantee any outcome, as you may see in the documentation of the [exec](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#exec) function and should be avoided.

See another detailed response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535284/exec-and-variable-scope)