# exec has different side effects in different contexts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a library that involves codegen, and I'd like to test that the code I'm generating is doing what I expect it to. I want to generate the code, `exec` it, and then verify that the result is what I expect it to be. However, I'm finding that when I do this in my test functions, the variable I set in the generated code aren't visible. For instance, this works perfectly:

```
exec('a = 1')
print(a)
```

However, this fails with a `NameError`:

```
def demo():
    exec('b = 2')
    print(b)

demo()
```

What gives?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [exec() and variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535284/exec-and-variable-scope) & [How does exec work with locals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1463306/7942856)

Comment: `With an explicit globals dict and no explicit locals dict, exec will use the same dict for both globals and locals` this sounds about right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly from my understanding, you cannot use exec like that in a function. Instead you can store this in a dictionary as shown below.

```
def demo():
    varDict = {}
    exec("b=2", varDict)
    print(varDict["b"])
demo()
```

output

```
2
```