# Command exec in a function, name error - python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, exec, python-exec

I'm begginer in Python and I'm in front of a problem that I can't understand. I tried to just define a variable with a exec() and then just print it. And it's working well. BUT when I do the same code in a function, it's not working...

Example :

```
def fonct():
    possibilite = [0,1,2,3]
    testc = 0
    testl = 1
    commande = "proba"+str(testc+1)+str(testl)+" = possibilite"
    exec(commande)
    print(commande)
    print(proba11)
```

The same thing but not in a function has for result, that the command print(proba11) returns [0,1,2,3] so it works. But for the example I got this :

```
proba11 = possibilite
NameError: name 'proba11' is not defined
```

There is no stories about globals or locals, everything is local...

Comment: There is no variable named proba11, that's why you have this error. First, define proba11 if you want to print it

Comment: But when I do the same code, without defining proba11 but not in a function it's working. So I was thinking that it was ok to not define it, I will try, thank you.

Comment: `proba11 = possibilite` came because of this code `commande = "proba"+str(testc+1)+str(testl)+" = possibilite"`. It is just a string, not a variable

Comment: So you can't print it out

Comment: Ok, I tried, in the first lines of the function, I wrote proba11 = [0]. And the print(proba11) returns [0] and not [0,1,2,3].... So I think the exec() is not working as expected but I don't know why... I used it in other conditions and this is the only place I got problems....

Comment: The line "proba11 = possibilite" pop out because of the line "print(commande)" to make sure the command is well wrote.... And then I execute commande. So it should define proba11...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the local variables with `exec()` in Python 3 is tricky due to the way local variables are stored. It used to work in Python 2.7 and earlier.

To workaround this, you need to

- Pass an explicit `locals` dictionary to `exec`
- Grab the newly defined variable from the updated locals dictionary

Like so:

```
def fonct():
    possibilite = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    testc = 0
    testl = 1
    varname = "proba" + str(testc + 1) + str(testl)
    commande = varname + " = possibilite"
    _locals = locals()
    exec(commande, globals(), _locals)
    proba11 = _locals[varname]
    print(proba11)
```

Which works as expected.

You can read more about it here:

- [exec() and variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535284/exec-and-variable-scope)
- [How does exec work with locals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals)

Comment: Thank you very much ! It was just a trick a didn't know about, thank you for teaching me this !