# execute a function inside another function

Tags: python, function, configparser

I have this configuration file (test_conf.txt):

```
[function]
exptime1 = |def foo(f):
           |    result=float(f['a'])
           |    return result
```

and this code that works without problem

```
c = configparser.ConfigParser()
c.read('test_conf.txt')
e1 = compile(c['function']['exptime1'].replace('|', ''), '', 'exec')
exec(e1)
f = {'a':2, 'b':'3'}
print(foo(f))
```

nevertheless, when I put this inside another function:

```
def run():
    c = configparser.ConfigParser()
    c.read('test_conf.txt')
    e1 = compile(c['function']['exptime1'].replace('|', ''), '', 'exec')
    f = {'a':2, 'b':'3'}
    exec(e1)
    print(foo(f))
```

I have this error:

```
NameError: name foo is not defined
```

using `dir()` the function foo is in the NameSpace but somehow it is not recognized

Comment: not positive, but try putting `global foo` at the top of `run()`. Could be that `exec(e1)` is affecting global scope

Comment: @LeiYang can you tell me where, I don't seem to see where this is happening

Comment: @LeiYang does not change anything.

Comment: @Quelklef does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me reproduce your problem without any config parser.

*common section*

```py
e1 = '''def foo(f):
    result = float(f['a'])
    return result
'''

f = {'a': 2, 'b': '3'}
```

*working*

```py
exec(e1)
print(foo(f))
#outputs 2.0
```

*not working*

```py
def run():
    exec(e1)
    print(foo(f))

run()
NameError: name foo is not defined
```

I got same output by `exec(e1,globals())`. [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45535337/1518100)

*disclamation*

I'm not sure how it works, but it does work for your current problem.

Comment: Yes! this works too! Awesome!  I actually prefer this option :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ok from a related question on the right of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string?rq=1) I could solve the problem with

```
locals()['foo'](f)
```